# Python print and write output end in ". . ." rather than the complete line

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried moving around the strings and variables I am concatenating, using while loops, moved the line and method that I am opening the outfile, etc. No matter what I do my output prints/writes "curl" + my *url* variable. From there it ends in "..." **ex: curl "https://examplesite/...**

Does this have something to do with a buffer or slicing problem? Thank you for any and all help. Full code below.

```
import pandas as pd

# file = open("output.txt","wt")
header_list = ["COLA", "COLB"]
df = pd.read_csv("curl_data.csv", names=header_list)

df_length = len(df)

iterator = 0
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        url = '"https://examplesite'
        lic = df.COLA # use %20 instead of spaces
        name = df.COLB # use %20 instead of spaces
        group = "example group" # use %20 instead of spaces
        command = "curl " + url + "license=" + lic + "&name=" + name + "&group=" + group + '"'
        print(command)
        file.write(str(command))
        iterator += 1
        if iterator == 1:
            break
        
file.close()
```

Comment: This script won't do that. I suspect it's being done by whatever you use to view the file.

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: `lic = df.COLA` shouldn't it be `row.COLA` instead? Probably the output just becomes super long because you concatenate in the entire column.

Comment: I have tried viewing my output in the console, vscode, notepad++, IDLE and all still display the ellipses rather than the full line.

Comment: I am not using Jupyter Notebook @Barmar

Comment: You should write a newline to the file after each line.

Comment: `if iterator == 1: break` means it will only write the first line to the file.

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(len(command))`? Is it the length of the string with `...` or the full length?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As Imre Kerr suggested in the comments the problem was with the length of the output.

I changed my for loop to be `for i in range(len(df)):` this only looped through the dataframe once (as per Barmars suggestion) and changed the references to the columns in my code from `df.COLA` to `df.loc[i, "COLA]` so that it did not print the whole dataset everytime. This fixed the problem of the lines being too long and thus I was able to see the full line for each outputted string.